# _POST Time Data not appearing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a large form I'm trying to make MySQL update syntax changes.

I have two separate date/time boxes that merge together into a strtotime for the MySQL entry.

The date works but the time does not in the POST data. I attempted to echo the POST `dataDowntime` data but nothing appears.

**MySQL Query Response:**

```
    $startTime = $row['startTime'];
     $startTimeConv = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($startTime)); // Date Conversion
     $startTimeConvTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($startTime)); // Time Conversion
```

**Update Form PHP:**

```
<input type="date" id="dataDate" name="dataDate" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $startTimeConv // load time from db ?>">

<input type="time" id="dataDowntime" name"dataDowntime" value="<?php echo $startTimeConvTime // Load time from db ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
```

**Update Form Submit PHP:**

```
      $newDate = $_POST["dataDate"];
      $newDowntime = $_POST["dataDowntime"];
      $newStartTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("$newDate $newDowntime"));  // Merging Date/Time for Downtime
```

**echo $newStartTime:**

```
2016-08-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have problem in form, missing `=` symbol in name of `dataDowntime`:-

```
<input type="date" id="dataDate" name="dataDate" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" value="<?php echo $startTimeConv // load time from db ?>">

<input type="time" id="dataDowntime" name="dataDowntime" value="<?php echo $startTimeConvTime // Load time from db ?>" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
```

Comment: sigh.. Thank you. .. all those hours wasted. :)

Comment: @AndyHinkle Accept answer, Welcome